# Get Encrypted Values through Custom Filter layer and decrypt it and then pass it to Controller in .net API 7.0

Tags: .net, encryption, asp.net-core-7.0, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

I am creating a .net core 7.0 APIs which are end to end encrypted. Data is first encrypted at API level and then pass it to Android application, same from android to .Net APIs.

What should be the best practice to do

1. Create custom filter where we can decrypt all the requests and make it as model and then pass the decrypted model to controller (If yes please suggest any help which returns modified request parameters)
2. Create a method at controller level that connect with Encryption/Decryption Layer and return the Model to Controller